# My custom view don not show backgroundColor

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created a view , and set two attributes, `backgroundColor` and `backgroundAlpha`, when i set `v.background = color`, the backgroundColor is blue, but when i set `v.background = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:b]` , the backgroundColor is clear, as if the b is zero;

```
+ (instancetype)initWithBgrColor:(UIColor *)color bgrAlpha:(NSInteger) b
{
    view *v = [[view alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:b];
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What is the value you are passing at b?

Comment: Change the b value and check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not be watching the output of the compiler to see that Xcode is warning you about the parameter types. Per the documentation, the alpha value parameter to colorWithAlphaComponent is a CGFloat between 0.0 and 1.0, therefore, your NSInteger is not correct. Change your code to be like this:

```
+ (instancetype)initWithBgrColor:(UIColor *)color bgrAlpha:(CGFloat) b
{
    NSLog(@"initWithBgrColor: b = %f", (float)b);
    view *v = [[view alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:b];
    return v;
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor?language=objc